# How to create fixture where there is relation between two tables in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, django-fixtures, symfony-4.2

I have two entities say '**User**' and '**Address**' in which I have '**OneToOne**' relation between them.

**User table** has a column '**address_id**' which is **Foreign key**, stores the id of **Address table**.
I have tried to create fixture by using 2 different methods:

Method 1:

**AddressFixture.php**

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Address;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class AddressFixture extends Fixture
{
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $address = new Address();
        $address->setStreet('Sai Apartment');
        $address->setCity('Noida');
        $address->setState('Uttar Pradesh');
        $address->setCountry('India');
        $address->setPincode('201301');
        $manager->persist($address);
        $manager->flush();
        if (null != $address->getId()) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFName('Kumar');
            $user->setLName('Saurabh');
            $user->setUsername('supa-admin');
            $user->setPassword(
                $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, 'querty')
            );
            $user->setEmail('some_email@gmail.com');
            $user->setAddress($address);
            $user->setContact(78954);
            $user->setGender('male');
            $user->setAge(26);

            $user->persist($user);
            $manager->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2:

In this I have created two different Fixtures:

**AddressFixture.php**

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Address;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class AddressFixture extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $address = new Address();
        $address->setStreet('Sai Apartment');
        $address->setCity('Noida');
        $address->setState('Uttar Pradesh');
        $address->setCountry('India');
        $address->setPincode('201301');
        $manager->persist($address);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

**UsersFixture.php**

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class AddressFixture extends Fixture
{
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFName('Kumar');
            $user->setLName('Saurabh');
            $user->setUsername('supa-admin');
            $user->setPassword(
                $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, 'querty')
            );
            $user->setEmail('some_email@gmail.com');
            $user->setAddress($address);
            $user->setContact(78954);
            $user->setGender('male');
            $user->setAge(26);

            $user->persist($user);
            $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Then I ran:

> $ php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load

*Both ways did not gave me the required result. How to create Fixtures when Foreign key is used between both tables?*

Comment: The first one looks fine - you can drop out the `if (null != $address->getId())` part and do the flush just once after both entities are created and persisted. Or what exactly is not working for you in the first version? If you want to use separate fixtures you should take a look how the fixtures can be ordered and how previously created entities can be accessed from [doctrine sharing objects between fixtures](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures)

Comment: There is a little mistake `$user->persist($user);`. It should be `$manager->persist($user);` in method 1

Comment: @Constantin: thanks buddy for pointing out. It was a silly mistake from my side.

Comment: In method 2, in file UsersFixture.php, the class should be named `UsersFixture` instead of `AddressFixture `. Also I don't understand from where the variable `$address` comes from.
You can use the `$manager` to find your `$address` entity.

Answer (score 6):

You should implement `DependentFixtureInterface` in your `UserFixture`:

```
class UserFixture extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{

   public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            AddressFixture::class,
        ];
    }

}
```

So when you try to get reference for your User, `SymfonyFixturesLoader` will load all dependencies. Then in your `UserFixture` just inject it to your address field:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
   $user = new User();
   // ...
   $user->setAddress($this->getReference(AddressFixture::FIRST_ADDRESS));
}
```

Do not forget to set reference on the AddressFixture side:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
   $address = new Address();
   // ...
   $this->setReference(self::FIRST_ADDRESS, $address);
}
```

Comment: where did the FIRST_ADDRESS came from? I receive `Undefined class constant 'FIRST_ADDRESS'`